# Как в списке поменять строковые значения на булевы?

Tags: python, list

```
[['кирпич', '2', 'False'], ['шпатель', '3', 'False'], ['камень', '5', 'False'], ['лестница', '2', 'False']]
```

Надо поменять строковые 'False' на булевы `False`, при этом сохранить формат списка

```
[['кирпич', '2', False], ['шпатель', '3', False], ['камень', '5', False], ['лестница', '2', False]]
# такой результат должен быть
```

Просто замена через цикл рушит структуру.

Comment: А откуда в списке `'False'`? Мб лучше исправить тот код, что такое заполняет? :)

Comment: Это все в строке приходит, потом уже получается этот массив, надо именно чтоб тут менялось.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как формируется массив. А то получается костыль, ведь странно, что там булевое значение в виде строки, а потом нужно его снова сделать булевым... А так поменять не проблема, что-то вроде `items = [['кирпич', '2', 'False'], ['шпатель', '3', 'False'], ['камень', '5', 'False'], ['лестница', '2', 'False']]` + `new_items = [[row[0], row[1], row[2] == 'True'] for row in items]`

Comment: @gil9red а если там тупо вообще каждый третий элемент подсписка одинаков и равен строке "False", то еще проще :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать словарь замены и проверять вхождение ключа в него через метод `dict.get(key, value)`, где `value` — возвращаемое значение для случая несуществующего ключа. А дальше пересобрать список с его помощью.

```
income = [['кирпич', '2', 'False'], ['шпатель', '3', 'False'], ['камень', '5', 'False'], ['лестница', '2', 'False']]
map_dict = {'false': False, 'true': True}
res = [[map_dict.get(e.lower(), e) for e in r] for r in income]
```